# How do I extend .each so elements inside the loop have a last? method to check if element is the last one?

Tags: ruby

I want to extend `.each` method on arrays to achieve a syntax like this:

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
arr.each do |el| puts i unless el.last? end
```

Obviously I can do this:

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
arr.each_with_index do |i, index| puts i unless index+1 == arr.length end
```

but I like to abstract away this logic into a `last?` method.

How do I do it?

Comment: Add a method to the object being yielded. But meh.

Comment: What if the objects in the array already have a `last?` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the objects being yielded is the wrong way to do it, since the object itself shouldn't be aware of its inclusion in a given collection (and what if you had the same object in multiple arrays?)

If you're wanting to just avoid operating on the last item in an array, why not something like:

```
arr[0..-2].each {|elem| ... }
```

You could also extend Enumerable with a variation on Darshan's second answer, allowing you to exclude the last element in any given enumerable:

```
module Enumerable
  def except_last
    each_with_index do |el, index|
      yield el unless index == count - 1
    end
  end
end

[1,2,3,4,5].each.except_last {|e| print e }
1234
```

(In this case, the `each` is actually redundant, but it's nice and readable with it in there.)

Comment: I do want to iterate with last item too, I just want to have a flag that says it's the last item.

Comment: Darshan's first answer is your best bet, then. Use a block variable rather than a method on the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close:

```
def each_with_last(arr)
  arr.each_with_index do |el, index|
    yield el, index + 1 == arr.length
  end
end

arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
each_with_last(arr) {|el, last| puts el unless last}
```

As Dave Newton points out, you *could* add a `last?` method to the object being yielded rather than yielding an additional boolean value, but, as icktoofay points out, that could get messy.

If your real-life use case involves ignoring that last value, as you do here, this is cleaner, in my opinion:

```
def all_but_last(arr)
  arr.each_with_index do |el, index|
    yield el unless index + 1 == arr.length
  end
end

arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
all_but_last(arr) {|i| puts i}
```

**Update:** For the sake of completeness, although I recommend against it:

```
module Enumerable
  def with_last?
    each_with_index do |el, index|
      flag = index + 1 == count
      el.define_singleton_method(:last?) {flag}
      yield el
    end
  end
end

arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
arr.each.with_last? {|el| puts el unless el.last?}
```

That won't work if `arr` contains objects that can't have singleton methods defined on them, such as Symbols and Fixnums.

Of course, you could do this to `each` itself to make your example code work as given (other than the `el`/`i` typo), but that would escalate things from "recommended against" to "truly terrible idea".

Comment: It's worth noting that the technique that extends `#last?` onto the object is going to invalidate the method cache, which will utterly torch appwide performance.